# Error when reconfiguring grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a grid within the application. All works well. I then want to change the grid to use different columns from a saved configuration. This also works fine - UNLESS I open up a filter menu on a column first. After this, changing the column layout causes an error deep down within the reconfigure function, where the focus is being re-applied to the grid. Here is the code where the error happens in the Ext.view.Table class:

```
    onFocusEnter: function(e) {
    var me = this,
        fromComponent = e.fromComponent,
        navigationModel = me.getNavigationModel(),
        focusPosition,
        br = me.bufferedRenderer,
        focusRecord, focusRowIdx, focusTarget, scroller;
    // Focusing an internal focusable while TD navigation is disabled;
    // We do not intervene.
    if (me.actionableMode) {
        return;
    }
    // The underlying DOM event
    e = e.event;
    // We can only focus if there are rows in the row cache to focus *and* records
    // in the store to back them. Buffered Stores can produce a state where
    // the view is not cleared on the leading end of a reload operation, but the
    // store can be empty.
    if (!me.cellFocused && me.all.getCount() && me.dataSource.getCount()) {
```

The problem is that me.dataSource is null. I find this strange as the comment immediately before this line identifies the potential problem of an empty store when using a buffered store - which I am - and yet does nothing about it.

I am definitely providing a valid store into the reconfiguration function, as it works fine unless the filter menu is shown first. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at this further and examined why the dataSource value should be null. Well higher up the call stack we come through a Ext.util.StoreHolder class to bind the store. This includes code that binds the store to the listeners and then raises an event to let the system react to the change.

```
    bindStore: function(store, initial, propertyName) {
    ...
    if (store !== oldStore) {
        if (oldStore) {
            ... lines to unbind the old store
        }
        if (store) {
            me[propertyName] = store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup(store);
            me.bindStoreListeners(store);
            me.onBindStore(store, oldStore);
        } else {
            me[propertyName] = null;
```

Its down within onBindStore that the error happens. I added code before it to set the dataSource from the source and the error went away.

Though it works, I'm a little hesitant to do this as it is changing the real ExtJs code. If you can think of a better answer, please share it.